# Phonegap 3.3.0 with Camera Plugin Permission Error

Tags: plugins, cordova, permissions, camera

I created a project with cordova command line and add camera plugin.
And add some settings (http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera) 
I compiled and executed a example on that page with my galaxy s4 and it doesn't work.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13084)
        at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2038)
        at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:577)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

So i tried another example on github (https://github.com/heavysixer/phonegap-camera-sample).
It is worked with no errors.

What is the problem with above example?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error.
Seems the problem is with the Android Manifest file.
You need to include the following to make your camera app work

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Answer (score 0):

for android:

Terminal commands:

```
$ phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
$ phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.media
$ phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.media-capture


(in app/res/xml/config.xml)
    <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
    </feature>


    (in app/AndroidManifest)
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```